# How can I share Google Drive folders with a group?

Tags: google-drive, google-workspace, google-groups, google-drive-sharing, google-drive-shared-folder

I'm using Google Apps and trying to share a nested folder structure with many files with a google group.

### Example

**Group**
test@example.com

**Group Members**
user1@example.com
user2@example.com
etc.

**Shared Folder Structure**
parent/
parent/files

parent/folder-1/
parent/folder-1/files

parent/folder-1/folder-1.1/
parent/folder-1/folder-1.1/files

parent/folder-2/
parent/folder-2/files

parent/folder-2/folder-2.1/
parent/folder-2/folder-2.1/files

etc.

### Sharing with individual users works

If I share the parent directory with the users individually (i.e. user1@example.com), it works as expected:

- The folder structure shows up in the
  ***Folders Shared with Me*** section
- The files show up in the **Files
  Shared with Me** section

### Sharing with groups doesn't work

If I share the parent directory with a group (test@example.com) that contains the same individual users, it doesn't work as expected:

- The folder structure does **not** show up in the
  ***Folders Shared with Me*** section
- The files do **not** show up in the **Files
  Shared with Me** section
- However the files **do** show up in the All
  Files section

### Why isn't this working?

Any ideas why there are different behaviors when sharing with individual users vs. sharing with groups and is it possible to make this work?

Answer (score 2):

We have also seen some inconsistencies re. sharing of folders/documents not with groups but with all attached to our domain. Have you tried sending the group a link to the parent folder? When the link is clicked on it may then make that folder and its children visible to the group under "Folders Shared with Me".