# What is GoogleDrive permission merge policy?

Tags: google-drive, google-groups, google-workspace-for-business, google-drive-sharing

Suppose I have a Group that grants `Read` permission on specific file, and a User within the Group that has `Write` permission.
In that case, what is the permission conflict policy?

From the documentation I found that

> If you share content with a group that contains another group, the subgroup members have the same access to the content as the parent group member

(https://support.google.com/a/answer/167101?hl=en)

Is this always the case? The parent always "wins" ?

Comment: Welcome. Have you already tested this? What do you found?

Comment: I have not. I thought you guys will have some info about it (documentation does not says much)

Comment: I don't remember read Q/A here about sharing with nested groups. Anyway here are a couple of links to slight related Q/As: [How can I share Google Drive folders with a group?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/10612/88163), [Why can't new group members see a folder that I have shared with the group?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/66285/88163)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After doing an experiment, it seems that the most permissive permission wins:

If the User has `Edit` permission and the Group has `View` -> the user can still edit

If the User has `View` permission and the Group has `Edit` -> the user can still edit
(in is both in `TeamDrive` and `PersonalDrive`)